# Can i format url in jQueryValidate remote method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Ok, this works fine:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      remote: {
        url: "/ajax/check-email.php",
        mothod: "get",
        dataFilter: function( response ) {
          return response;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

this configuration automatically made a GET to url:

```
/ajax/check-email.php?email=EMAIL-TO-CHECK
```

The problem is that I have this API to query:

```
/ajax/email/EMAIL-TO-CHECK/exists
```

So I have to create the url to be queried at runtime, but I can't do it in any way.

I tried to do this, using $.ajax() directly:

```
remote: function( ele ) {

  var email = $(ele).val()

  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/email/"+ email + "/exists",
  }).done(function( xhr ) {
    return xhr
  });
}
```

ut the validation does not fire.

I also tried to use a function for get "url", but "email" is empy. Like this:

```
var createUrl = function() {
  var id = $("#myform input[name=email]").val(); //this is empty
  return "/manager/ajax/pricelist/" + id + "/exists"
}

$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      remote: {
        url: createUrl(),
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Any idea?
Many many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with the existing `remote:` method. From the [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The serverside resource is called via `jQuery.ajax` (`XMLHttpRequest`) and gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated element and its value as a GET parameter.

So this use of `?email=EMAIL-TO-CHECK` is built into the method, there's no opportunity to customize of.

The simplest solution for you would probably be to create a rewrite rule on your server that rewrites something like

```
/ajax/check?NAME=VALUE
```

to

```
/ajax/NAME/VALUE/exists
```

A more complex solution is to write your own validation method that's like `remote:` but allows you to provide a callback function to generate the URL.

Comment: Thank you man, you have been very clear.